# how to print out how many spaces, words, alphabets, digits, sentences, punctuations are in a text file

Tags: c, text-files, counter, ctype

So I have been working on a code that will scan and print out all the spaces, words, sentences, digits, alphabets, punctuations that are in the text file. also some of the text file will have another text file saved in it to also be read in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>


#define size 100
int words(char a[]);
int sentences (char a[]);
int sadp (char a[]);

int c;
char filename[size];
FILE *books, *books1, *books2, *books3;

int main(){
  books = fopen("files.txt","r");
  if(books == NULL){
    printf("File is not found\n");
  }
  else{
    while (fgets(filename, size-1 ,books) != NULL){
      printf("%s",filename);
      sentences (filename);
      words(filename);  
      sadp (filename);
    }
  }
  fclose(books);
  return 0;
}

int sentences (char filename[]){
  int count=0;
  char i=0;
  books3 =fopen(filename,"r");
  if (books3 !=NULL){
    while (fscanf(books3, "%d", &c)>0){
      for(i = 0; filename[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(filename[i] == '.')
          count++;
        }
      i++;
    }
  }
  printf("\tSentences:\t\t%d\n", count);
  return count;
}

int words(char filename[]){
  char i;
  int count=0;
  books2 = fopen(filename,"r");
  if (books2 != NULL){ 
    while(fscanf(books2, "%d", &c)>0){
      for (i = 0; filename[i] != '\0';i++){
        if (filename[i]==' ' || filename[i]=='\n')
          count++;
        }
      i++;
    }
  }
  printf("\tWords:\t\t\t%d\n",count);
  return count;
}

int sadp (char filename[]){
  int alpha, digit, space, punct, i;
  punct = 0; //for punctuations
  alpha = 0; //alphabets
  digit = 0; // digits
  space = 0; // spaces between the words
  i = 0; // place holder to count
  books1 =fopen(filename,"r");
  if (books1 != NULL){
    while(fscanf(books1,"%d", &c) > 0){
      if(isalpha(c)){
        alpha++;
      }//checks to see if it is alphabet
      else if(isdigit(c)){
        digit++;
      }//checks to see if it is digits
      else if(isspace(c)){
        space++;
      }//checks to see if it is space
      else (ispunct(c));
        punct++;
        //checks to see if it is punctuations
      i++;
    }
  }
  printf("\tLetters:\t\t%d\n", alpha);
  printf("\tDigits:\t\t\t%d\n", digit);
  printf("\tSpaces:\t\t\t%d\n", space);
  printf("\tPunctuations:\t%d\n\n", punct);
  return (alpha /*digit, space, punct*/ ); 
}
```

However when I go to print this out I will get all the titles in the file to print out. but the counts for each of things that I wan to print out will not print out.

Comment: Please augment your [mre] with sample input, current output, desired output. Also try to reduce the problem to only one thing (or two, for highlighting a difference between works/works not).

Comment: Please describe the role, the meaning of all occuring files.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to first read everything (while counting) and then at the end output a summary/overview of all counts? That you would hence never want to print anything within a loop?

Comment: First begin with one function, say `alpha, digit, space & punct`; `while(fscanf(books1,"%d", &c) > 0)` is not going to help you.

Comment: You really should avoid unnecessary global variables and maybe throw in a `fclose` to match every successful `fopen`.

Comment: Unrelated: the size in `fgets()` already takes into account the `'\0'`, so `fgets(filename, size-1, books)` possibly *wastes* 1 byte of memory from `filename` (BTW: `filename` is, in my opinion, a bad identifier for an object containing a line)

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to read a file thrice to find statistics you're looking for, once is enough; going by one character at a time.

**Alphabets, White-Spaces, Punctuations & Numerical-Digits**

```
int print_file_stats (char filename[])
{
    if (NULL == filename) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\nEmpty filename %s", __FUNC__);
        return -1;
    }
    int alpha = 0; //alphabets
    int digit = 0; // digits
    int punct = 0; //for punctuations
    int space = 0; // spaces between the words

    FILE *pFile = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (NULL == pFile) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\nReadingFile : %s", filename);
        return -2;
    }
    int iCh;
    while (EOF != (iCh = getc (pFile))) {
        if (     isalpha (iCh)) ++alpha;
        else if (isdigit (iCh)) ++digit;
        else if (isspace (iCh)) ++space;
        else if (ispunct (iCh)) ++punct;
    }
    fclose (pFile);

    printf ("\tLetters:\t\t%d\n", alpha);
    printf ("\tDigits:\t\t\t%d\n", digit);
    printf ("\tSpaces:\t\t\t%d\n", space);
    printf ("\tPunctuations:\t%d\n\n", punct);
    
    return (alpha + digit + space + punct);
}
```

Function `int getc(FILE *stream);` will read the file one character at a time. Note it returns EOF (of size more than one byte) when it reaches end-of-file.

**Words**

Any alpha-numeric grouping separated by white space. When `isspace()` is true & it comes after one/more alpha-numeric chars then we just crossed a `word`.

**Sentences**

Any grouping of words terminated by sentence terminators (. ! ?). Meaning, ... !!! ??? are false positives for sentences.

```
> Is this a sentence
> "How about this? Take it"
```

Let's keep it simple for the time being. When `ispunct()` is true & it(. ! ?) comes after one or more words then we found a sentence.

You just have to keep flags(for word & sentence) of where you're and count words & sentences.